# Get Image on Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I am using Google Maps API in my app, when I search a location and click information button, it will show a windows with name, address, image.
I copied func getPhoto() from google maps doc:

```
private Bitmap getPhotos() {

    Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(Maps.mPlace.getId());
    photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> task) {
            try {
                // Get the list of photos.
                PlacePhotoMetadataResponse photos = task.getResult();
                // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos).
                PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
                // Get the first photo in the list.
                PlacePhotoMetadata photoMetadata = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
                // Get the attribution text.
                CharSequence attribution = photoMetadata.getAttributions();
                // Get a full-size bitmap for the photo.
                Task<PlacePhotoResponse> photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPhoto(photoMetadata);

                photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoResponse> task) {
                        PlacePhotoResponse photo = task.getResult();
                        bitmap = photo.getBitmap();
                        ImageView imageView = mWindow.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        imageView.refreshDrawableState();

                    }
                });
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("aaa", "onComplete: IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    });
    return bitmap;
}
```

And I place it into a func to get imformation:

```
private void rendowWindowText (Marker marker, View view) {
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);

    if (!title.equals("")) {
        tvTitle.setText(title);
    }

    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    TextView tvSnippet = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_snippet);

    if (!title.equals("")) {
        tvSnippet.setText(snippet);
    }

    getPhotos();

}
```

Now my problem is when I search a place and hit button to show marker's info, my imageview is nothing:

[image: green background in my xml]

And when I click that button to close windows and click again to show marker's info, the image is loaded:

[image]

Somebody can tell me how to fix that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may helps you

```
 private void rendowWindowText (Marker marker, View view) {
        String title = marker.getTitle();
        TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
   ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (!title.equals("")) {
            tvTitle.setText(title);
        }

    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    TextView tvSnippet = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_snippet);

    if (!title.equals("")) {
        tvSnippet.setText(snippet);
    }

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               imageView.setImageBitmap(getPhotos())
            }
        });


}

//And getPhotots() like this,


private Bitmap getPhotos() {

    Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(Maps.mPlace.getId());
    photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> task) {
            try {
                // Get the list of photos.
                PlacePhotoMetadataResponse photos = task.getResult();
                // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos).
                PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
                // Get the first photo in the list.
                PlacePhotoMetadata photoMetadata = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
                // Get the attribution text.
                CharSequence attribution = photoMetadata.getAttributions();
                // Get a full-size bitmap for the photo.
                Task<PlacePhotoResponse> photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPhoto(photoMetadata);

                photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoResponse> task) {
                        PlacePhotoResponse photo = task.getResult();
                        bitmap = photo.getBitmap();

                    }
                });
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("aaa", "onComplete: IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    });
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: oops I forget to tell you that this class is a adapter class, I can't use runOnUiThread method. Any recommend?